# Loading of content without changing URL or calling any JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I came across a website where there are multiple pages. And when a page is clicked content is dynamically loaded. I know that AJAX is used but I could not understand how it works without calling any JavaScript function. Here is the piece of code:

```
<a href="#" class="acted" onclick="return false;">1</a>

<a href="#" onclick="return false;">2</a>

<a href="#" onclick="return false;">3</a>
```

Is there something I’m missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get that code from "Show source"?  If so, it's likely that there was a script run on the page to dynamically wire up the event handlers once the page is loaded, so those onclick events in the raw HTML might just be placeholders.

Example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="main">This text is not clickable and has no action when clicked, but try to click me anyway just in case.</div>
</body>
<script>
    window.onload = function()
            { 
               document.getElementById("main").onclick = function() {
                                    return alert('Actually, I am clickable afterall!');
                                };
            };
</script>
</html>
```

On the above page, there is a div called "main" that has no default onclick action.  However, when the page loads, an event fires (in this case window.onload) which calls some code to attach a function to the onclick attribute of the div with id "main".  The result is that main becomes clickable even though the raw HTML did not include a default handler and you won't see the handler if you do "view source" (though if your browser has developer tools you may be able to see it wired up).

I have also provided this in a JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qfazj/2/

(If you are not familiar with JSFiddle, the bottom right corner is where the web page is rendered, so click the text there and you should see the alert happen.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing something. We can't know for sure without seeing the full code, but this page is likely using jquery selectors to handle the events. For example the code might state that all "a" tags get a certain javascript function associated with them. Or everything with class="acted", etc. Have a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: but how action is taken for click event if no function is called..There should be a onclick function where jquery is used right?